# Mapbox GL - getWaypoints

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How to call getWaypoints in Mapbox GL and parse the result?

```
  mapboxgl.accessToken = '<token>';
            var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                container: 'map',
                style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
                center: [lng, lat],
                zoom: 12
            });

            var directions = new MapboxDirections({
                accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken                
            });


            map.addControl(directions, 'top-left');
```

UPDATE: User is able to display a path on a map, what I am trying to do is display markers within 25 miles to the path. Now all my markers are on the map and I need to find steps of the path (lat, long) so I can calculate distance between path and marker in order to display on needed markers.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to and where you're getting stuck?

Comment: @SteveBennett edited my question.

Comment: @Ika
  Do you need straight line distance or drive/walk/cycling times to the markers? This feature may help if it lands: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6062